# React Native error: undefined is not a function

Tags: android, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am starting to learn React Native.  I am following a tutorial and have written the following code:

```
var React = require('react-native');

var {
  Text,
  View,
  AppRegistry
} = React;

var StopWatch = React.createClass({
  render: function() {

  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('stopwatch', function() {
  return StopWatch;
});
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating 'React.createClass({displayName:'StopWatch', 
render:function render() {}
})')
```

I run React Native in the Android simulator, using the command

```
react-native run-android
```

The file is

```
App.js
```

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't really answer your question, but why do it this way using deprecated syntax?

Try the facebook react-native tutorial here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html

Or better yet, use the wonderful [create-react-native-app](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app)

This should get you up and running

Comment: ah ok thanks.  I am following a tutorial I bought on udemy, and the class was probably made a while ago.  what parts of the code are deprecated?

Comment: `React.createClass` is deprecated, and pretty much everyone in the React world is only using es6 for everything now.